# What is the best way to include 100s of words inside the code?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

I am writing a program that will access several hundred words frequently, so instead of storing them all in a .txt file and having to use cpu and hard drive to access, process and store in a vector I want to include them inside the program. What is the best way to go about doing that? (while keeping source code clean)

The program will identify nouns using pronouns, verbs, etc... in a question.

(I am using MV)

*edit
I guess the best option is to load data into the program upon initialization, based on responses below.

Comment: Why put them in the code? Don't do that. Read them into memory once and refer to that. Hundreds of words doesn't sound like a big deal?

Comment: Is loading them into memory during application start-up not acceptable? That's a cheap solution, in terms of processor and access time.

Comment: You don't really gain anything by putting them inside the `.exe` (except now the `.exe` is somewhat self-contained) since the CPU still needs to access the hard drive to load the executable image in memory anyway. Hundreds of words takes almost no time at all to load from a text file on a non-ancient computer, and since it'll be in memory it'll be just as fast when indexing into them. And if I need to change the list of words for some reason, I can't do it without asking you to recompile the `.exe`.

Comment: IMO, the benefits of putting the data into a file far outweigh the pro of not having to access the drive.  What if you want to add a word later, or you want to provide localization?  Scaling this to a thousand words or more doesn't seem reasonable when placing the words directly in the code.  Also, *if* your searching the container of words and you don't want duplicates, it seems like using std::set *may* be a better option.

Comment: @In silico With a signed exe you can guarantee that embedded way has not been tampered with

Comment: @parapura rajkumar: You can also verify the authenticity of all your input files using the same digital signature/cryptographic hash techniques used to sign executables. It's nothing you couldn't do yourself.

Comment: When you say *"access several hundred words frequently"*, what do you mean by "access"? Do you linearly traverse **all** the words or perform some kind of search to get just one or few of them at a time? Do you need any kind of sorting? Are there any relationships between words? Do you need insertion/modification/deletion? Perhaps clarify what you mean by: *"The program will identify nouns using pronouns, verbs, etc... in a question."*?

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic it is not yet finalized, but what I am thinking of right now (and have coded) is that there are certain words in the english language that never get modified or increased like pronouns. Right now I am taking the question and searching every word through a list of pronouns, once a pronoun is identified the next word might be a noun. If it checks out then the next word is tested for a verb, if a verb not found then it is likely a noun and is returned. Program than searches through a text file containing the answer for that noun and returns the sentence where it is present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to store them program in a array like so if they are already known at compile time.

```
std::string words[] =
{
  "foo" ,
  "bar" 
};

or

const char* words[] =
{
  "foo" ,
  "bar" 
};
```

And within the program you can access them likes `words[0]` and `words[1]` etc etc. Depending on your operating system programs are also allowed to have embedded resources. You can use that approach as well.

You can also store them as you are doing currently as well. Hunderds of words should be read in pretty quickly. Extraneous file has an advantage that they can be changed without recompiling the file. But might suffer from the disadvantage that when you distribute your program you have to distribute your extra file as well. Users may muck around with a plain text file and you will have to handle malformed input file too.

You haven't mentioned how you are planning to access these words. Depending on that you might need other data structures like `set` , `map` or maybe even a `Trie`

Comment: I would recommend using std::string instead for security and maintainability

Comment: I would recommend using std::array instead for security and maintainability

Comment: @Kos how does std::array enhance security ? Also I am not sure C++11 is that widespread yet

Comment: @Kos I personally this a vector is better than std::array for this task. Using container initializer list with an array still means you have specify the size of the container. This is sub optimal (as though you are going to count the number of element in the intializer list. Whereas a vector will just take 'however many are present in the list.

Comment: gawd, is this the battle of the abstractions? This is completely static data initialized right at the beginning of the program. How exactly would a vector be superior? Why bother with the `array` class? And why not just use `const char*`'s? (That would allow the array to be set up statically, instead of having to run constructors and perform heap allocations)

Comment: @jalf Couldn't agree mroe ... I have updated the answer .... If only I had a nickel for every time my answer was downvoted for using char* instead of std::string and P* instead of smart pointers.

Comment: Well, for dynamic data, I'd absolutely use `std::string`, and sure, `array` or `vector` as well. But here we're dealing with hardcoded strings generated statically and never modified. Jumping through hoops to use as much as possible of the standard library is just silly

Comment: @jalf I did mention in my answer that depending on how you want to access them use appropriate data structures.

Answer (score 4):

If not C+11 you could use `boost::assign::list_of` to initialize the list:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

const std::set<std::string> words = boost::assign::list_of("word-one")
                                                          ("word-two")
                                                          ("word-three");
```

Using a sorted container would be preferable to unsorted (enabling use of `lower_bound()`) if you are going to be searching the `words`, and that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 3):

Don't include these words as part of your executable.  They may not change in your eyes, but an error means recompiling and redeploying your application.

100s of words is not an overhead.  Neither is 1000s.  Do the sensible thing and put them in a text file.  Write some code to read them in to an array (there are plenty of examples on how to do this if you google it).  Then you only ever have to edit your text file to correct typos that are sure to appear even with the most careful hands.

I know this does not strictly answer your question, but I also believe in trying to save other people's frustrations at bad decisions :)

Comment: +1 for "I know this does not strictly answer your question, but I also believe in trying to save other people's frustrations at bad decisions :)"

Answer (score 1):

in C++98 to have such a list statically initialize and conveient to type you need to use an array.

```
std::string word_list[]={
    "first", "second", "third"
};
```

This can then be load into a vector like so

```
std::vector<std::string> word_vect(word_list, word_list+100);
```

Another way is to use the boost libaries += operator for containers.

```
std::vector<std::string> word_list;
word_list+="first", "second", "third" //and so on
```

see here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html#operator+=

However in c++11 you can do this:

```
std::vector<std::string> word_list{
   "first", "second", "third"
};
```

Of course you can store then to a file and load them in (space separated)

```
std::vector<std::string> word_list; //create empty vector
word_list.reserve(100);             //reserve 100 spaces (this is for efficiency)

std::ifstream file("path_to_file"); //open file
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(file),  //read all worlds
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
          std::back_inserter(word_list));       //append to vector
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the answer to this depends on what you intend to do with those words. For instance, if you are going to be looking up for a particular word regularly from this huge list, it would be better to go for a dictionary structure - where lookup time is just the number of characters in the "needle" string.